# Matlab: Sorting 2D matrix and retaining nodes in triangle groups

Tags: matlab, sorting, matrix-indexing

I am trying to optimize a Matlab script (below) that finds the bounding boxes to functional values of all lower left triangles in a 2D space. The code goes through all the triangles and then sorts the nodes in ascending order based on the functional values. This seems inefficient.

Is there some way that I could sort the functional values before the loops but still retain the nodes in the triangle groups? Or some other smart way to speed things up?

```
clear;

x = (1:600)';
y = (1:500);
z = 2 * x.^2 + y;

zGrid = linspace(min(z, [], 'all') - 1, max(z, [], 'all') + 1, 200);

for iX = 1:length(x) - 1
    for iY = 1:length(y) - 1
        % Node indices
        xIndices = [iX, iX, iX + 1];
        yIndices = [iY, iY + 1, iY];

        % Node values
        xTmp = x(xIndices);
        yTmp = y(yIndices);
        zTmp = z(sub2ind(size(z), xIndices, yIndices));

        % Node sorted according to z
        [zSorted, indicesSorted] = sort(zTmp);
        xSorted = xTmp(indicesSorted);
        ySorted = yTmp(indicesSorted);

        % Get bounding box on zGrid
        iMin = find(zGrid <= zSorted(1), 1, 'last');
        iMax = find(zGrid(iMin:end) >= zSorted(end), 1, 'first') + (iMin - 1);
    end
end
```

Comment: You can use meshgrid to generate all the indice: `[iX,iY] = meshgrid(x(1:end-1),y(1:end-1))` and then `iX = iX(:)`,`iY = iY(:)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use meshgrid to generate all the indices, then just adapt the code to obtain the desired ouput:

```
x = (1:600).';
y = (1:500);
z = 2 * x.^2 + y;

zGrid = linspace(min(z(:)) - 1, max(z(:)) + 1, 200);
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x(1:end-1),y(1:end-1));
X = X(:);
Y = Y(:);

% Node indices
xIndices = [X, X, X + 1];
yIndices = [Y, Y + 1, Y];

% Node values
xTmp = x(xIndices);
yTmp = y(yIndices);
zTmp = z(sub2ind(size(z), xIndices, yIndices));

% Node sorted according to z
[zSorted, indicesSorted] = sort(zTmp,2);
xSorted = xTmp(indicesSorted+[0:3:(length(X)-1)*3].');
ySorted = yTmp(indicesSorted+[0:3:(length(Y)-1)*3].');

% Get bounding box on zGrid
% I use fliplr to get the last value and not the first one
[~,iMin] = max(fliplr(zGrid <= zSorted(:,1)),[], 2);
iMin = 200-iMin+1; %first to last value conversion
[~,iMax] = max(zGrid(iMin:end) >= zSorted(:,end),[],2);
iMax = iMax + iMin -1;
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! But the `iMax = iMax + iMin -1;` that was in the earlier version is still needed for `iMax` to be correct. Now, I'm just going to wrap my head around to understand it :)

Comment: Ok I was not sure about that (in fact I'm not sure to understand what is going on with this code :p), I rolledback to the previous edit. The `[0:3:(length(X)-1)*3]` vector   is just here to cumulatively add +3 to each row so the linear index point to the right value.

Comment: I just realized that the rows in your `xSorted` and `ySorted` in don't correspond to the objects in my code. `zSorted`, `xTmp` and `yTmp` are exactly the same. So, the problem seems to be with using `indicesSorted`. Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I think that the problem comes from the triangle nodes are grouped in rows and not columns together with how Matlab orders cells in linear indexing.

Comment: @Fredrik P, ho yeah, you can simply transpose those two matrix:  `xTmp = x(xIndices).';` and 
`yTmp = y(yIndices).';` so the linear index will be in the "right" direction. A linear index is performed column by column and not row by row.